# Performance of order by on indexed vs non-indexed column

Tags: sql, oracle

For sql query like

```
select * from <TABLE_NAME> order by <COLUMN_NAME_INDEXED>
```

vs

```
select * from <TABLE_NAME> order by <COLUMN_NAME_NOT_INDEXED>
```

will the performance/cost be same or different w.r.t relational dbms?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to get here. Are you really looking for a yes / no answer? Is this homework? We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am expecting the impact of index on column used in order by clause. This isn't homework but I was trying to fetch  records ordered by columns in large dataset. I am considering to put index but index has it;s own cost .

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and then [ask]. This is too broad.

Comment: @PrashantThorat Are you sure your pseudo-code is accurately representing real-life queries?  It's unusual for a query to not have a WHERE clause.  And if you care about performance, I assume the tables are large, and then it's very unusual to select everything from a large table like this.  Ordering is usually only done for display purposes, but not many programs are going to display a large number of records.  Once you start filtering records, the answer will likely change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an index does improve the performance of an `ORDER BY`.

Sorting is by design expensive in terms of CPU and memory. On the other hand, indexes do represent the data in a sorted manner. When a proper index exists, your RDBMS will (under certain conditions) use it instead of doing the sort in memory.

Comment: thanks. This means that first query will run faster compared to second one right ?

Comment: Yes in this simple case it will. On a very small resultset, you probably won't notice the difference. But the bigger the resultset gets, the greater will be the performance gain.

Comment: Thank @GMB that answers the question

Answer (score 1):

I was rather surprised to find that an index can help (tested on Oracle 12.2).

Test table with 1M rows:

```
create table demo_sort
( num_indexed      integer not null
, num_unindexed    integer not null
, str_indexed      varchar2(50) not null
, str_unindexed    varchar2(50) not null
, date_indexed     date not null
, date_unindexed   date );

insert /*+ append */ into demo_sort
     ( num_indexed
     , num_unindexed
     , str_indexed
     , str_unindexed
     , date_indexed
     , date_unindexed )
select num, num
     , str, str
     , dt,  dt
from   ( select round(dbms_random.value() * 1e5) as num
              , dbms_random.string('x',50) as str
              , date '2010-01-01' + numtodsinterval(dbms_random.value() * 1e5, 'HOUR') as dt
         from   dual connect by rownum <= 1e6 );

create index demo_sort_num_ix on demo_sort(num_indexed);
create index demo_sort_str_ix on demo_sort(str_indexed);
create index demo_sort_date_ix on demo_sort(date_indexed);

call dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'demo_sort');
```

Test performance using SQL*Plus [AUTOTRACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-C8FBE008-B2D6-4049-A095-0747E5328A50) (showing best time for three runs). The default execution plan and resulting performance was the same:

```
SQL> set autotrace trace exp stat
SQL> set timing on
SQL> select * from demo_sort order by str_unindexed;

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:18.92

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3213928767

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |  1000K|   122M|       | 33771   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |           |  1000K|   122M|   139M| 33771   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEMO_SORT |  1000K|   122M|       |  5233   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        135  recursive calls
          3  db block gets
      18627  consistent gets
      17242  physical reads
          0  redo size
  141711618  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     733933  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      66668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          1  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed


SQL> select * from demo_sort order by str_indexed;

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:19.06

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3213928767

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |  1000K|   122M|       | 33771   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |           |  1000K|   122M|   139M| 33771   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEMO_SORT |  1000K|   122M|       |  5233   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        136  recursive calls
          3  db block gets
      18627  consistent gets
      17242  physical reads
          0  redo size
  141711618  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     733933  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      66668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          1  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed
```

However, when hinted to use an index, performance is around 40% faster (although we are still only talking about 11 seconds instead of 19 to sort 1M rows - and this is on my laptop and not a production-grade database server):

```
SQL> select /*+ index(d) */ * from demo_sort d order by str_indexed;

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:11.04

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2822485249

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                  |  1000K|   122M|  1009K  (1)| 00:00:40 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEMO_SORT        |  1000K|   122M|  1009K  (1)| 00:00:40 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN           | DEMO_SORT_STR_IX |  1000K|       |  7770   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
    1074381  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
  141711618  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     733933  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      66668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed
```

So avoiding the sort made up for having to do 57 times more I/O, resulting in a modest improvement. (It appears that the optimiser was as surprised as I was - notice that the computed cost is 30 times higher for the index approach).

Just to summarise, the two approaches are:

1. Read all the rows from the table in one pass, and perform a sort on the results.
2. Read all the rows from the index in one pass, and for each index entry fetch the corresponding row from the table.

The first approach uses less I/O as it can use a multi-block read, and probably direct path, to scan the table in one shot.

The second approach performs one million table lookups, in addition to scanning the entire index once. Since the table's data is physically stored and cached in blocks, a lot of those blocks will be hit multiple times and so accessing the whole table this way is far less efficient in terms of I/O, even accounting for caching. As it happens, in this case it was still marginally worth it to avoid the sort.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  On very small data sets, the sorting algorithm may take very little time -- and there is overhead for loading an index and using it.

For more than a handful of rows, *typically* ordering by an indexed column is going to be much more efficient.  Sorting is an expensive operation -- I recall that it is O(n log(n)) and most algorithms require reading and writing the data multiple times.

There is another exception for very large tables or in a very memory constrained environment.  A situation called *thrashing* can occur, where the data pages (for the `select *`) do not fit in memory.  When the size is much larger than available memory, you can get into a situation where every record is likely to require reading a page not in memory.

This has very, very bad performance -- worse performance than actually sorting the data.

Note that in most databases thrashing would not occur if you are using a covering index (i.e. an index that includes all columns in the query).

However, under most circumstances, using an indexed column is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. In case of large data sets if I use order by on indexed columns will dbms engine do sort operation after fetching data or will it output data directly as indexes are already sorted?

Comment: @PrashantThorat . . . It outputs the data as the indexes already return the rows in sorted order.  Databases are pretty smart about this.  For instance, if you have an `order by` after a `group by` with the same keys *and* the database uses sorting for the `group by` (there are other algorithms), then no additional sorting is performed.